# Situation-dependent bookmark level of \subsubsection

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

Is it possible to have `\subsubsection`s add their bookmarks at different levels? In my case it is at the respectively lowest level that interesting features become visible, but these are (in absolute terms) not the same levels

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Three}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Four}

\chapter{Sample Two}
\section{Subsample One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Three}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Four}
\section{Subsample Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Three}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Four}

\chapter{Sample Three}
\section{Subsample One}
\subsection{Subsubsample One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Three}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Four}
\subsection{Subsubsample Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Three}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Four}

\end{document}
```

The reason why I would like to have it all in `\subsection`s is that I would like to underline the similarities by eye-catchingly typesetting the section headers,

```
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]
```

but then the bookmark tree looks very unfortunate, [image]

My idea would be to overcome this letting `\subsubsection` using `\belowpdfbookmark{text}{name}` instead of `\pdfbookmark[level]{text}{name}`, but how do I do that? Or are there better approaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `hyperref` requires that intermediate section levels are present.
Thus you get some warnings.

Package `bookmark` reimplements `hyperref`'s bookmark managing using a more robust algorithm and can therefore handle the case of missing intermediate section levels:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
  open,
  numbered
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Three}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Four}

\chapter{Sample Two}
\section{Subsample One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Three}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Four}
\section{Subsample Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Three}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Four}

\chapter{Sample Three}
\section{Subsample One}
\subsection{Subsubsample One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Three}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Four}
\subsection{Subsubsample Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic One}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Two}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Three}
\subsubsection{Characteristic Four}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Imho in your example `\usepackage{bookmark}` is missing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. Cut&paste error, the unmodified example was pasted.